# How to setup laravel relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I'm using Larvel 5.3 and I have four tables I wish to set up relations with.

```
- Users
- Orders

- Products
- Brands
```

An order belongs to a user and a user has many orders.
A product belongs to many orders and additionally, to one brand.
A brand has many products.

I'm trying to find a way to get a user's order, with the products AND the brand of the products.

User.php

```
public function orders(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

Order.php

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function products(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Product.php

```
public function orders() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Orders');
}
public function brand(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand');
}
```

Brand.php

```
public function products() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Flavour');
}
```

I wish to get back an array containing the users orders, along with each orders products and the products' brand.

Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Products and Orders have a many to many relationship.

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

Get a user's order first. Because users have many orders, you need to specify which order you want to view the products list from.

```
$order = $user->orders->first();
```

Then get all products and their brand

```
foreach($order->products) ...
```

For your super array, you can try Eager Loading

```
$arr = User::with('orders.products.brand')->get(); //Not tested
```